# What is the umbrella term for credit cards and debit cards?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What is the umbrella term for credit cards and debit cards? "Payment cards" or something? "Cash cards"?

Comment: In most contexts, just ***cards*** would be understood. Informally, ***plastic***. But it's a somewhat arbitrary distinction anyway. There are many different "sub-types" of both credit and debit cards (and the associated ***accounts***), plus many financial institutions are now starting to offer products / services that combine some or all aspects of both card types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard a few ways of saying it, probably in this order of likelihood:

> [You can pay by] card

> Credit or debit card

> [We accept all] cards

> Payment cards

I also hear "credit card" in some circumstances where the meaning actually also includes debit cards.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia they are, as you suggest, known as payment cards.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_card

If you are in a shop or restaurant and you have some doubts about acceptance though you would just ask "Do you take cards?" or some variant of that. The phrase payment card is somewhat technical.